# Angular variable value change doesn't reflect in DOM

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular component (`SummaryComponent`) which is injected with a service (`LicenseRequestService`). A variable (`totalLicense`) of the component is defined to be equal to a calculated field from the service.

The component class is written as below :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LicenseRequestService } from '../shared/license-request.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sg-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _service : LicenseRequestService) {

   }

   public totalLicense= this._service.licenseDetails.length


  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  updateSummary(){
    const licenses= this._service.licenseDetails.length
    console.log("total players requested : " + players)
    this.totalLicense= players
  }

}
```

I have embeded the `totalLicense` value into the DOM as below :

```
<div>
    Total number of licenses is : {{totaLicense}}
</div>

<button type="submit" (click)="updateSummary()">Get licenses</button>
```

Everytime the service gets updated, I expect the DOM to reflect the updated value of `totalLicense` but it stays 0. However, when I click the button labeled `Get licenses`, the DOM is then updated and the `totaLicense` variable shows the new value in the browser.

Do I need to make any changes to make sure the value of `totalLicense` gets updated without clicking the button (which is the desired functionality)?

Comment: from where u are updating `licenseDetails` in `LicenseRequestService` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're not passing a reference you are passing a value. Basically if you have the following:

```js
let x = 'test';
let y = x;
x = 'update';
console.log(y);
```

This code will output 'test', not 'update' because y is still pointing at the original value

There are three solutions I can think of offhand:

1. Reference the service itself in the html (you'd have to make it not private)
2. Add licenseDetails as a variable in your component instead. This way when you access the length variable it will be by reference, not by value
3. Use a getter (not suggested since it is an antipattern, since it causes the function to run on each change detection cycle)

Comment: Thank you! referring the service in the html did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this `public totalLicense= this._service.licenseDetails.length` code `constructor` or `ngOnInit`

Comment: Thank you for your response. That doesnt work either, I still have to click the button to update. I guess it is because when the component is generated , at that time the service doesnt have any value for the ```licenseDetails.length```

Comment: Yes, It might be possible